# Using one function to clear one of multiple ListBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, button, listbox

I have three `ListBoxes` and three 'clear' `buttons`, one for each of those three `Listboxes`. Right now, I have all of the 'clear' `buttons` linked to the same click-function. In that function, I use a `switch` to determine which `ListBox` to clear. I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of the `switch` statement and replace it with one line of code that determines which `ListBox` to clear. I need something that links each `button` with the corresponding `ListBox`. I messed around with the `Tag` property of the `Buttons` but didn't have luck there.

Here's the code currently:

Xaml (ClearBtn1 clears lb1, etc.):

```
<Button Name="ClearBtn1"
        Click="ClearBtn_Click"
        Content="Clear" />

<Button Name="ClearBtn2"
        Click="ClearBtn_Click"
        Content="Clear" />

<Button Name="ClearBtn3"
        Click="ClearBtn_Click"
        Content="Clear" />

<ListBox Name="lb1" />

<ListBox Name="lb2" />

<ListBox Name="lb3" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string name = btn.Name; //Gets the button name which corresponds to a certain listbox

    switch (name)
    {
        case "ClearBtn1":
            { ClearListBox(lb1); return; }
        case "ClearBtn2":
            { ClearListBox(lb2); return;}
        case "ClearBtn3":
            { ClearListBox(lb3); return; }
    }
}

public void ClearListBox(ListBox listbox)
{
    listbox.Items.Clear();
}
```

With the `Tag` I was trying something like:

```
<Button Name="ClearBtn1"
        Click="ClearBtn_Click"
        Content="Clear"
        Tag="lb1" />

private void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, Rout
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string name = btn.Name; 

    ClearListBox(btn.Tag); //doesn't work
}
```

This doesn't work since I can't cast a `string` to a `ListBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the element to the tag, rather than just the string:

```
<Button Name="ClearBtn1"
    Click="ClearBtn_Click"
    Content="Clear"
    Tag="{Binding ElementName=lb1}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to get the expected result.

```
<Button Tag="{Binding ElementName=lb1}"  Name="ClearBtn1"
    Click="ClearBtn_Click"
    Content="Clear" />

<Button Tag="{Binding ElementName=lb2}"  Name="ClearBtn2"
    Click="ClearBtn_Click"
    Content="Clear" />

<Button Tag="{Binding ElementName=lb3}"  Name="ClearBtn3"
    Click="ClearBtn_Click"
    Content="Clear" />

<ListBox Name="lb1" />

<ListBox Name="lb2" />

<ListBox Name="lb3" />
```

And modified the ClearBtn_Click as below

```
private void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    var list = btn.Tag as ListBox;
    ClearListBox(list);
}
```

Comment: This works, @joe just answered first. Thank you for the alternative option!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

Keep your listBoxes in a List of type ListBox.
Like

```
List<ListBox> listBoxes = new List<ListBox>();
listBoxes.Add(lb1);
listBoxes.Add(lb2);
listBoxes.Add(lb3);
```

And put index number as Command Parameter on each of the button

```
<Button Name="ClearBtn1"
        Click="ClearBtn_Click"
        Content="Clear"
        CommandParameter="0" />

<Button Name="ClearBtn2"
        Click="ClearBtn_Click"
        Content="Clear" 
        CommandParameter="1"/>

<Button Name="ClearBtn3"
        Click="ClearBtn_Click"
        Content="Clear"
        CommandParameter="2" />
```

Then in your Button Click Function

```
private void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, Rout
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    int index = int.Parse(btn.CommmandParamter);

    ClearListBox(index);
}
```

Now your ClearListBox function will receive an index as parameter rather than a list box.

```
public void ClearListBox(int index)
{
    listBoxes[index].Items.Clear();
}
```

Hope that solves your issue.